# Selenium. I want to perform right click operation using (first option)contextclick(), but it is throwing error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've tried this code:

```
    Actions act=new Actions(driver);
    act.context click(). perform();
```

Comment: Please post the html and what exception is getting thrown

Answer (score 0):

if thats the exact code than the problem is the space in contextClick(), it should be:

```
act.contextClick().perform();
```